# adding UI features to DataTables top bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am quite new to the datatables jquery plug in and was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem I am having.

So the datatables plug in looks something like this in the beginning
[image]

but I was wondering if I could add a slight feature to the top bar to make it look something like this : it seems like a simple UI change but I cant find out where.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: DataTables provides a plugin API. Have you looked here http://datatables.net/plug-ins/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at DataTables plugin called "Editor":

Plugins page: http://datatables.net/extras/

Example: https://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/index.html

Once you get the "Add" functionality, you can place it anywhere using CSS.

Good luck with implementation 
Vrutin